# ruby create sub arrays if element includes same letter

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array like this:

```
["b3", "a3", "a5", "b2"]
```

and I need to get it to this:

```
[["b3", "b2"] ["a3", "a5"]]
```

I have tried various things including:

```
["b3", "a3", "a5", "b2"].map { |i| i.include? 'a' }
# => returns [false, true, true, false]
["b3", "a3", "a5", "b2"].detect { |i| i.include? 'a' }
# returns "a3"
```

Is there an simple way for this to be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
a = ["b3", "a3", "a5", "b2"]

a.group_by { |s| s[0] }.values
  #=> [["b3", "b2"], ["a3", "a5"]]
```

[Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) produces:

```
h = a.group_by { |s| s[0] }
  #=> {"b"=>["b3", "b2"], "a"=>["a3", "a5"]}
```

and then we use [Hash#values](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-values) to extract the values:

```
h.values
  #=> [["b3", "b2"], ["a3", "a5"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Before reading this answer @Cary's answer is optimised and best. But I think what you were trying to do is this

```
["b3", "a3", "a5", "b2"].select{|e| e.include?('a')}
=> ["a3", "a5"]
```